# Invalid Return Code from Greengrass Discovery

Tags: aws-iot-greengrass

Using the AWS IoT Device [SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2.git) from GitHub, I'm testing from my local machine using the basic_discovery.py script I can see that it returns the IP address and port from my Raspberry PI running as a Greengrass device, however, I see that I'm getting invalid return codes from the subsequent request when it is attempting to connect with the PI device. The error messages I am getting are as follows:

```
Trying core arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:111111111111:thing/GreengrassPI at host 192.168.1.176 port 8883
[ERROR] [2022-07-20T20:42:02Z] [00007000017de000] [mqtt-client] - id=0x7fd8b24b4b60: invalid connect return code 4, disconnecting
[ERROR] [2022-07-20T20:42:02Z] [00007000017de000] [tls-handler] - id=0x7fd89242aba0: error reported during SSLRead. OSStatus code -9805
Connection failed with exception AWS_ERROR_MQTT_PROTOCOL_ERROR: Protocol error occurred.
All connection attempts failed
[ERROR] [2022-07-20T20:42:02Z] [0000000116728e00] [mqtt-client] - id=0x7fd8b24b4b60: Connection is not open, and may not be closed
```

Any suggestions as to what to check? I did not see anything on this in the troubleshooting guide.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] So what I found was that the device name I was using in the test script was not listed in the client device associations for the Greengrass core device. Adding the association resolved the problem. For anyone else that runs into something similar refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/associate-client-devices.html) for information on associating devices. In summary what happened is that the script was able to look up the Greengrass core device but when it attempted to send an MQTT message to it, the Greengrass core device refused it because the device was not associated to it.